# Datastage list jobs

Tags: datastage

I am trying to execute a command from datastage job for list listing all the jobs in a project which are in aborted/crashed/stopped status. The command I am using is given below.

```
/opt/IBM/InfoSphere/Server/DSEngine/bin/dsjob -domain XXXXX:9445  -user XXXX-password XXXXX-server XXXXX -ljobs -status 3/96/97 DEV.
```

But its giving me the below error

```
Command Syntax:
    dsjob [-authfile <authfile> | -file <file> <domain> <DataStage server> |  [-domain <domain> | -url <url>] -user <user> -password <password> -server <DataStage server>] | -domain <domain> [-user <user>] -server <DataStage server>
            <primary command> [<arguments>]

Valid primary command options are:
    -run
    -stop
    -lqueues
    -lprojects
    -ljobs
    -linvocations
    -lstages
    -llinks
    -projectinfo
    -jobinfo
    -stageinfo
    -linkinfo
    -lparams
    -paraminfo
    -log
    -logsum
    -logdetail
    -lognewest
    -report
    -jobid
    -import

Status code = -9999 DSJE_DSJOB_ERROR.
```

Any idea on this

Answer (score 1):

Add the -server option - this option is missing in my eyes.

```
-server <enginename>
```

Dokumentation can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.3.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.cliapi.ref.doc/topics/r_dsvjbref_The_Logon_Clause.html)

Comment: Thank you.. But some how its not working for me. Is there any command which I can used to retrieve the job status

Comment: An alternative could be to check the DSODB once set up you could retrieve this information using SQL. Although I double checked you statement and it looks fine ssuming your ports are the right ones configured during installation. Sometimes you need to specify the hostname including a domain (like myserver.company.com) and sometimes without it - I is worth a retry (server and domain could need different formats)... give it a try

Comment: Yea as you mentioned I give a try with domain and server name as well..But not working.

Comment: Also is there any way I can list all the jobs within a folder in Datastage

Comment: Have you checked out DSODB?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but it could help someone else.

Michael already told you to add the "-server" option (don't forget the space).
Now if you only want aborted and warning job, add the "status" option with the status code you want:

```
dsjob -ljobs -status 3/96/97 my_DS_project
```

List of status code (from the IBM doc):

- 1 "Finished"
- 2 "Finished (see log)"
- 11 "Validated OK"
- 12 "Validated (see log)"
- 21 "Has been reset"
- 99 "Compiled"

NOT Runnable Job Status (reset job)

- 0 "Running"
- 3 "Aborted"
- 13 "Failed validation"
- 96 "Crashed"
- 97 "Stopped"
- 98 "Not Compiled"

Valentin

Answer (score 0):

try excluding the logon details (server/user/password), it will try using the current user name on same server